# Docker Reverse Proxy Ingress on Swarm

Tags: docker, networking, service, dns, reverse-dns

We operate a `docker cluster` with several workers and a manager.

Our current problem:

We have the `Jwilery Nginx proxy` running on all nodes which does not cause any problems. What causes us problems is, if we operate a service e.g. `grav`.
This is only then available, if the domain points to the IP address on which the service is running at that time.

My question now:

Is there a way to route the domain in such a way that we only have to set an `A-record` and `Docker` does the `internal routing` on the respective node where the website is running?

If yes, how would we realize this or are there other alternatives with which this is easier to implement?

Useful information:

```
1 manager

4 workers

a total of 5 ip addresses (Public)
```

All `Barebone` Server with `Docker (Without Kubernetes etc.)`

```
1 decentralized data server with NVME
```

Website can be called if the domain points to the `judge Worker Target 1 Public IP` for all domains with failover incl. Internal routing to the respective workers.

Resources:

To implement this, no resources are a shame. Other servers could also be used for this scenario.

ps: You could also contact me in other ways for testing purposes etc.pp.